# ¿Como aplicar estilos a un botón desde código en Android?

Tags: android

Que tal amigos, la inquietud del día es como aplicar estilos desde el código en Android, tengo un botón que en un principio tiene el color verde, pero en cierta ocasión quisiera cambiarlo a un color diferente desde es código.

> Código XML

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_message_white_24dp"
        style="@style/boton_info_valido"/>
```

> Estilos

```
<style name="boton_info_valido">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/bt_info_valido</item>
  <item name="android:paddingStart">5dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingEnd">5dp</item>
</style>
<style name="boton_info_invalido">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/bt_info_invalido</item>
  <item name="android:paddingStart">5dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingEnd">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Como pueden apreciar el botón cuenta con el estilo `style="@style/boton_info_valido"`, que es un color verde ahora desde el código quisiera aplicar el otro estilo `boton_info_invalido`.

Espero su colaboración hasta pronto.

Comment: Ya lo solvente de la siguiente manera: `Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.bt_info_invalido);
        mIbFacebookInfo.setBackground(drawable);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aplicar el estilo es precisamente como lo realizas, definiendo el estilo mediante la propiedad `style=`:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_message_white_24dp"
        style="@style/boton_info_valido"/>
```

Si deseas aplicar el estilo  `@style/boton_info_invalido` , simplemente definelo a tu botón:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_message_white_24dp"
        style="@style/boton_info_invalido"/>
```

---

Si lo que deseas es que cambie este estilo mediante una acción, por ejemplo un "touch", se puede realizar mediante un `listener` y no necesitas definir el estilo, simplemente la imagen que carga cada estilo, `bt_info_valido` o `bt_info_invalido` :

```
  final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_info_invalido); //invalido!
                return true;
            }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_info_valido); //valido!
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```